# replace a string in file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose my file a.conf is as following

```
Include /1
Include /2
Include /3
```

I want to replace "Include /2" with a new line, I write the code in .sh file :

```
line="Include /2"
rep=""
sed -e "s/${line}/${rep}/g" /root/new_scripts/a.conf
```

But after running the sh file, It give me the following error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: By editing your question to substantively change what you're asking, it is very hard to vote meaningfully on answers; indeed, the answer you accepted no longer addresses the question. Perhaps you should rollback and post a new question.

Comment: I thought that was my answer, but when a new criteria came, then I was bemused, sorry for that.

Comment: I would like to point out when you say "__I want to replace "Include /2" with a new line__ you are in fact replacing the string with nothing. It's `sed` that is providing the newline once you have finished your editing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of sed you can use **-i** to read from and write to the same file. Using **-i** you can specify a file extension so a backup will be made, incase something went wrong. Also you don't need to use the **-e** flag unless you are using multiple commands

```
sed -i.bak "s/${line}/${rep}/g" /root/new_scripts/a.conf
```

I have just noticed that as the variables you are using are quoted strings you may want to use single quotes around your sed expression. Also your string contains a forward slash, to avoid any errors you can use a different delimiter in your sed command (the delimiter doesn't need to be a slash):

```
sed -i.bak 's|${line}|${rep}|g' /root/new_scripts/a.conf
```

Comment: I'm using shell script, and single quotes do not give the variable replacement necessary.  Double quotes replaces ${rep} with the proper value.

Comment: This answer does not work (because of the slash character in the text). so no answer for this ?

Comment: Cheers for the pointer about being able to use a delimited other than `/`

Answer (score 4):

You have to write the changes to a new file and then, move the new file over the old one. Like this:

```
line="Include 2"

rep=""

sed -e "s/${line}/${rep}/g" /root/new_scripts/a.conf > /root/new_scripts/a.conf-new

mv /root/new_scripts/a.conf-new /root/new_scripts/a.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

The redirection (`> /root/new_scripts/a.conf`) wipes the contents of the file before `sed` can see it.

You need to pass the `-i` option to `sed` to edit the file in-place:

```
sed -i "s/${line}/${rep}/g" /root/new_scripts/a.conf
```

You can also ask sed to create a backup of the original file:

```
sed -i.bak "s/${line}/${rep}/g" /root/new_scripts/a.conf
```

Comment: Hey, your answer is correct but I have a new problem now. Look at my question again.

Comment: Please dont mind, if this question is mark solved then nobody answered this.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you have to replace a substring in a file, you can use sed command like this, say we have a file as file.txt, so replacing a substring in it can be done like this

```
searchString="abc";
replaceString="def";
sed -i '' "s|$searchString|$replaceString|g" file.txt
```

> This will all the occurrences of "abc" with "def" in file.txt. Also, this keeps a check for any / character present in the variables used, and with no backup file made.